# Does laravel 5.0 work in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, mysql, 16.04, xampp

I had previously ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed and I have so many projects on `laravel 5.0`. After the release of Ubuntu 16.04 I installed it on my machine and I am facing a lot of difficulties to get `laravel 5.0` working in it. I installed `Xampp 7.0.5 / PHP 7.0.5`. There were errors about `mbstring` and `mcrypt` I got rid of those errors by installing them from terminal. Now when I try to run `php artisan serve` it throws `[PDOException] Driver not found` error. In my `phpinfo` I can see `PDO`drivers for `mysql`, `pgsql`, `sqlite` are enabled.

The requirement of `laravel.5.0 says PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7`, so I also tried installing `Xampp 5.6.20 / PHP 5.6.20` and downgrading the php version of 16.04 to php5.

Is there any way I can get my `laravel 5.0` projects working on Ubuntu 16.04? 
I am wondering if `laravel 5.0` has worked in 16.04 for other people. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try using docker or vagrant, that way you won't have these problems after update

Comment: @Alen Ty Alen for response, But now I have installed ubuntu 15.10 and laravel 5.0 is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that L5 works fine with PHP7 on Ubuntu 16. Actually, i'm using it right now. Installation from composer.

Comment: do you mean laravel 5.0 works in PHP7 without downgrade?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm mean it. I was using Ubuntu 15, but I upgrade it to Ubuntu 16 (from Ubuntu notice about upgrade), so if I had php5 in Ubuntu 15, now I have php7 and my laravel project still working.

Comment: I installed ubuntu 16.04 and couldn't get it working after trying for some days. I even downgraded php  7 to php 5 thinking as if it was the problem. There were just endless of errors. I was running late on time to continue my projects so i just removed it and strarted fresh with 15.10 and its working fine.